# Debugging on Dolphin browser for android

Tags: debugging, browser, dolphin-browser

How could I inspect element on Dolphin browser? Few months ago, I debugged by chrome dev tools, but it's not working from now. Plz, help me to debug on Dolphin with Chrome dev tools or FireFox. Thanks